# How to check if a dynamically created Label is clicked and Change its colors?

Tags: c#, winforms

To be honest I don't really think there should be a big mess/problem with my code, but somehow the colors are not being changed when I click on a label!

What I was trying to achieve there was, if the user clicks `Male` then it changes color to green and the other Label, `Female`, changes back to red, and the opposite.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Label RB = new Label();
    RB.Location = new Point(x,y);
    RB.Width = 95;
    RB.Text = LabelsText[4].Split('-')[i];
    RB.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
    RB.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    RB.Font = new Font(family.Families[0], 11.0f, FontStyle.Bold);
    RB.ForeColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
    RB.Name = txtBoxNames[4].Split('-')[i];
    RB.MouseClick += (s, ev) =>
    {
        if (((Label)(s)).Name == "isMale")
        {
            ((Label)(s)).BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
            ((Label)(s)).ForeColor = Color.Black;

            foreach (Control ct in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ct is Label)
                {
                    if (((Label)(ct)).Name == "isFemale")
                    {
                        ((Label)(s)).BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
                        ((Label)(s)).ForeColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Refresh();
            this.Update();
        }
        else if(((Label)(s)).Name == "isFemale")
        {
            ((Label)(s)).BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
            ((Label)(s)).ForeColor = Color.Black;

            foreach (Control ct in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ct is Label)
                {
                    if (((Label)(ct)).Name == "isMale")
                    {
                        ((Label)(s)).BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
                        ((Label)(s)).ForeColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    this.Controls.Add(RB);
    x += RB.Width + 10 ;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it?

Comment: names :             

string[] txtBoxNames = new string[] { "fullName", "cinRef", "mainAddr", "phoneNbr","isMale-isFemale","birthDate" };

Comment: All controls are dynamically created.

Comment: @LarsTech Dbg is unavailable at the moment :p .

Comment: @ErikPhilips  Well yeah .. so ?

Comment: Why would it be unavailable?  Just put a stop on the `if (((Label)(s)).Name == "isMale")` line and step through the code line by line as it runs, inspect the variables.

Comment: @LarsTech ikr ? but actually unavailable its a bug that im facing lol !

Comment: Use [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) to make your code much more readable.

Comment: @ErikPhilips  Thanks for the advice :D but its pretty much my way of doing things !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for-each loops, you are changing the "sender" control back to PaleVioletRed instead of the label you found:

Change this:

```
if (((Label)(ct)).Name == "isFemale") {
  ((Label)(s)).BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
  ((Label)(s)).ForeColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
}
```

to this:

```
if (((Label)(ct)).Name == "isFemale") {
  ((Label)(ct)).BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
  ((Label)(ct)).ForeColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
}
```

Comment: Very Much Appreciated i just noticed that !

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding the two controls to the `this.Controls` collection, you can access the other *gender* using its Name: `this.Controls["ButtonName"]`:

You can also cast `object s` to `Control` to simplify the syntax:

```
var lbl = (s as Control);
```

Some more cuts here and there.

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Width = 95;
    label.Location = new Point(x + (i * label.Width) + (i * 10), y);
    label.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
    label.ForeColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
    label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    label.Name = "isMale-isFemale".Split('-')[i];
    label.Text = label.Name;
    label.MouseClick += (s, ev) =>
    {
        var lbl = (s as Control);
        string other = lbl.Name.Equals("isFemale") ? "isMale" : "isFemale";
        lbl.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        var ctl = this.Controls[other];
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            ctl.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
            ctl.ForeColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
        }
    };
    this.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the effort , realy amizing cuts !
You just made my whole life easy !!
Thaaank you A lot !